# Pull value from dictionaries embedded in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have pandas dataframe:

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $overall | {'all': 26929} | {'all': 2036} |
| QWE | {'$overall': {'all': 6},'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 3},'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 3}} | {'$overall': {'all': 3},'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 2},'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 1} |

Desired output :

| Name | Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ |  | 26929 | 2036 |
| QWE | Mar 3, 2021 | 3 | 2 |
| QWE | Mar 18, 2021 | 3 | 1 |

I tried below code and got below output:

```
df = df.apply(lambda s: s.str['all']).fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
```

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 26929 | 2036 |
| QWE | 0 | 0 |
| QWE | 0 | 0 |

`df.dict()` gives me below:

````
{'A': {'$XYZ': {'all': 26929},   
'QWE': {'$overall': {'all': 6},    
'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 3},    
'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 3}}, }  '
B.': {'$XYZ': {'all': 2036},   
'QWE': {'$overall': {'all': 3},    
'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 2},    
'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 1},   }  
'Name': {'$XYZ': '$overall',   
'QWE': 'QWE',   }}}```
````

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes. It looks like they're just python dictionaries.

Comment: That is correct. Its dictionaries.

Comment: Is that the entire input dataframe, or is this just a sample? It's not immediately clear what format each column/cell has and what logic should be implemented. Please add clarifying details.

Comment: @SSD can you include a snippet with the result of `df.to_dict()`? I can't reproduce `df` properly like this

Comment: The `QWE`-row doesn't contain dictionaries: your sample shows invalid Python objects?

Comment: I have updated my question, and `df.dict()` gives me below:

```{'A': {'$XYZ': {'all': 27026},
  'QWE': {'$overall': {'all': 6},
   'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 3},
   'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 3}},
}
 'B.': {'$XYZ': {'all': 2042},
  'QWE': {'$overall': {'all': 3},
   'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 2},
   'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 1},
  }
 'Name': {'$XYZ': '$overall',
  'QWE': 'QWE',
  }}}```

@Driftr95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 'XYZ', {'all': 27026}, {'all': 2042} ], 
    [ 'QWE', {'$overall': {'all': 6}, 'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 3}, 'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 3}}, {'$overall': {'all': 3}, 'Mar 3, 2021': {'all': 2}, 'Mar 18, 2021': {'all': 1}}]
], index=['$XYZ', 'QWE'], columns=['Name', 'A', 'B'])
```

[image: origDF]

---

There's probably a more elegant way to do it [maybe with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) on the dictionary or [`.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)...], but this should work:

```py
nested_index = 'Date'
expand_rows = ['QWE'] # include indices of rows with dates
expand_cols = ['A','B'] # include names of columns with dates

static_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in expand_cols]
exp_dfs = []
for ind in expand_rows:
    df_ind = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[ind][expand_cols].to_dict())
    df_ind = df_ind.drop('$overall',axis='rows')
    df_ind = df_ind.rename_axis(nested_index).reset_index()
    for c in static_cols: df_ind[c] = df.loc[ind][c]
    exp_dfs.append(df_ind.set_index(pd.Series([ind]*len(df_ind))))

exp_df = pd.concat([df.drop(expand_rows, axis='rows')]+exp_dfs)
exp_df = exp_df.applymap(lambda x: getattr(x,'get',{'all':x}.get)('all', x))
```

| `exp_df` | `exp_df[[*static_cols, nested_index, *expand_cols]]` | `exp_df.set_index('Date', append=True)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: exp_df] | [image: colsList] | [image: appendIndex] |